# Dual Status Tax eligible for Premium Tax Credit?

Tags: irs, dual-status

Me and my wife moved in the middle of year as Green Card Holders to the US. As I understand I am eligible for A PTC for Healthcare. If I file as Dual Status Alien (NR for 8 months and Resident for 4 months ) , which mandatory needs to file , each of the spouse as MFS , would I follow the 8962 instructions for repayment limit of APTC ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you talking about form 8962 line 28 (repayment limitation)? Why do you think you would not follow the instructions?

Comment: I just want to confirm that repayment limitation applies for Dual Status Aliens also . For a normal resident return i know that applies. there are certain credits ( and standard deduction) which don’t apply for Dual Status Returns